# Display card in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am writing a program simulating a single round of the card game WAR.

I don't know how to graphically display the card (number/color/suit).

```
import java.util.*; // for Scanner class
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;



// Class Definition
class Project4 {

    // Main method definition
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            // Object and Variable Declarations 
            JFrame win;
            Container contentPane;
            Graphics g;
            String player1Name, player2Name, scoreWinLoss;
            //This is the graphics portion, all of the graphics (so far) are working.
            win = new JFrame("War Game");
            win.setSize(900, 600);
            win.setLocation(100, 100);
            win.setVisible(true);
            win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            Color white = new Color(255, 255, 255);
            Color white2 = new Color(255, 255, 255);
            Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            Color black2 = new Color(0, 0, 0);

            contentPane = win.getContentPane();
            //Also if anyone knows how to change this .setBackground(Color.Green)from lime green to forest(card table) green that would be awesome!

            contentPane.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

            g = contentPane.getGraphics();
            Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25);
            g.setFont(font);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (Exception e) {}

            player1Name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Player 1, what is your name?");
            player2Name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Player 2, what is your name?");
            g.setColor(black);
            g.drawString(player1Name, 220, 35);
            g.setColor(black2);
            g.drawString(player2Name, 625, 35);

            g.setColor(white);
            g.fillRoundRect(125, 50, 250, 450, 20, 20);
            g.setColor(white2);
            g.fillRoundRect(525, 50, 250, 450, 20, 20);
            g.setColor(black);
            g.drawRoundRect(125, 50, 250, 450, 20, 20);
            g.setColor(black2);
            g.drawRoundRect(525, 50, 250, 450, 20, 20);

            //This is where it gets confusing and this stuff is all not working

            int card1Max = 14, card1Min = 2, card2Max = 14, card2Min = 2, randomNum1 = 0, randomNum2 = 0;

            g.setColor(black);
            g.drawInt(randomNum1, 150, 35);
            g.setColor(black2);
            g.drawInt(randomNum2, 500, 35);

            Random randomPicker = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
            randomNum1 = randomPicker.nextInt(card1Max - card1Min + 1) + card1Min;
            randomNum2 = randomPicker.nextInt(card2Max - card2Min + 1) + card2Min;

            if (randomNum1 < randomNum2) {
                scoreWinLoss = player2Name + " won!";
            } else if (randomNum1 > randomNum2) {
                scoreWinLoss = player1Name + " won!";
            } else if (randomNum1 == randomNum2) {
                scoreWinLoss = "It's a tie! Play again to determine a winner.";
            }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `JavaScript`?

Comment: `g = contentPane.getGraphics();` - You shouldn't do that. Create a `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent(Graphics)` method, and do the custom drawing there (don't forget to first call `super.paintComponent(Graphics)` inside it).

Comment: @LuxxMiner Why edit the post and not remove it?

Comment: @Berendschot I never like to edit such things like tags, maybe the OP just forgot to post the JS code (although I know that's very unlikely). I just edited the part where I was 100% sure about an edit wouldn't be wrong (= The code formatting). I also know now that my reasoning is stupid, because if the OP forgot to post code wouldn't change the fact that the current state of the question is not about JS... I will do better next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do not play with the graphics object like you are doing :

```
   g.setColor(black);
   g.drawString(player1Name, 220, 35);
```

This is bad!

Instead you should look at a layout. Look at **GridLayout**, or **GridBagLayout**. These allow you to organise JPanels as a grid. With these panels you can then set the background color and add text (via a JLabel).

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your problem: as simple way, you can use `JPanel` with `CardLayout` and then find card picture from web then, with `JLabel.setImageIcon(ImageIcon imageIcon)` method of `JLabel` set this pictures on it and by `CardLayout` bring up cards on toghether.